# Installing iFlyChat with Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to run iFlyChat with Symfony using their PHP client https://iflychat.com/installation/php-chat-client which I have successfully install using composer.

I've created an extension for the code:

```
<?php

namespace DW\UserBundle\Twig;

use DW\UserBundle\Service\UserService;
use Iflylabs\iFlyChat;

class ChatExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    /**
     * @var UserService
     */
    private $userService;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $appId;

    /**
     * @var string
     */
    private $apiKey;

    /**
     * @param UserService $userService
     * @param string $appId
     * @param string $apiKey
     */
    public function __construct(UserService $userService, string $appId, string $apiKey)
    {
        $this->userService = $userService;
        $this->appId = $appId;
        $this->apiKey = $apiKey;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return [
            new \Twig_SimpleFunction("chat", [$this, "chat"])
        ];
    }

    public function chat()
    {
        $iflyChat = new iFlyChat($this->appId, $this->apiKey);
        echo $iflyChat->getHtmlCode();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'chat_extension';
    }
}
```

but I get an error:

> Attempted to load class "iFlyChat" from namespace "IFlyLabs". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace?

Do I need to do something with the autoloader? I've been looking into registerPrefixes [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html) but that doesn't exist anymore for Symfony3.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the file name does not match class name, it's installed as `iflychat.php` while the class is `iFlyChat`. Renaming the file to `iFlyChat.php` works.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` so you can make sure there is an autoload namespace generated for IflyChat.

If there isn't you can execute:

`composer dump-autoload`

to force composer to regenerate the autoload for your dependencies.

Comment: It is there already `'Iflylabs\\' => array($vendorDir . '/iflylabs/iflychat-php/lib')`